# Thunderbolt peer to peer networking

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, thunderbolt

Hoping somebody has an idea to help me move forward. I am trying to connect two hosts with a Thunderbolt Cable as Networking devices and out of ideas.

If I run the Ubuntu Live CD in Desktop mode it works at 20Gb (with Linux Mac or Windows, also on more than one host), if I use the Ubuntu Server (which I need) it does not work, doesn't detect it at all. Both versions are 20.04 LTS.
Think by default they are using networkd vs NetworkManager renderers and I'm thinking that's the main issue but can't work out how to make NetworkManager detect the Thunderbolt0 interface on the Server OS. I've tried comparing installed packages and add anything that I've noticed might be network related but no luck.
Any advice?

Many thanks

Comment: On each of (working Live USB) and (Ubuntu Server) look at `sudo journalctl  -b 0` the startup logs. Also watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you dis- and re- connect the cable.

Comment: Thank you, I've run those, the -b 0 shows these only on the Desktop OS:

kernel: thunderbolt 0000:00:0d.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
systemd[1]: Started Thunderbolt system service.
kernel: thunderbolt 1-1: new host found, vendor=0x1 device=0x1

When plug-unplug the cable I can see plenty events just on Desktop OS again. Not sure how to add the log in here.

kernel: thunderbolt 1-1: new host found, vendor=0x1 device=0x1
...
systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.

So guess there might be something else missing

Comment: I've followed different ideas as well without any luck like:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/thunderbolt.rst?id=e69b6c02b4c3b8d03be7136f90dd9551ad5a5a5e

Comment: The devices I've tested with were 11th gen i7-1165 and i9-11900kb, tried with an older 8th i7-8665U with the same USB 20.04 Server install and worked fine.

Today upgraded the to the newly 22.04 LTS and that seems to work with 11th gen, so might be a driver after all for the 11th gen Intel. Annoyingly can't upgrade the hosts I needed this for yet.

linux-modules-extra were up to date on the 20.04, any idea what might be missing that I could add? As it obviously works with the Desktop version of 20.04.